# Force regular execution of periodic task within Java application

Tags: java, multithreading, scheduling

ScheduledExecutorService seems to have the problem that if it can't get a free thread the periodic task will happen with delay.  Unfortunately for me, the periodic task it's assigned to really does need to happen fairly on schedule.  At present it's scheduled for once per minute but sometimes due to the application being busy with other things (I assume this is why) it fails to make it within five minutes, and five minutes happens to be the "major production bugs" threshold.

How to force this via prioritizing or otherwise controlling the thread balancer?

Comment: Is your ScheduledExecutorService used for anything else but that task? Does your task always run in less than 1 minute?

Comment: Not enough information.  How are you actually scheduling the thread? Show some code.

Comment: @assylias - Bingo.  There's another task on this one that is taking that very long time and I have it programmed to only use one thread so I can avoid some concurrency coding issues.  I can solve by moving it to a separate executor service.  You can post this as an answer and I'll accept since they were the exact right two questions to ask.

Comment: @djechlin *"I have it programmed to only use one thread so I can avoid some concurrency coding issues."* => your task will run in its own thread anyway, so increasing the number of threads used by the executor should not bring any issues that you would not have with only one thread (unless I'm missing some specifics about what you have done).

Comment: @assylias there's 3 tasks running on this service.  The one that's urgent is lightweight and can run concurrently no problem.  The other 2 are both modifying the same set and it's not programmed carefully.  So the urgent task can be moved to its own service and get its own thread, as long as the two clashing ones stay single threaded (or unless I do the effort of making them parallelizable which is not worth it at this point).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your ScheduledExecutorService is used for other tasks or if your task sometimes takes more than 1 minute to run, you can simply increase the number of threads available in your ScheduledExecutorService. So if one task has not finished running, the executor will still be able to run a new one.

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(10);
```

(I picked 10 randomly - if you run your task every minute and it can run for up to 5 minutes, that leaves you some margin for error)